# mouseX and mouseY parameters in processing?

Tags: java, mouseevent, processing

Hi guys right now I am trying to get a bezier line to move in specific paremeters on the canvas with mouseX and mouseY in processing. I'm using the bezier as a mouth, and I want it to be controlled with the mouse by the user to look as if the face I am drawing is , smiling, sad, etc. but right now using mouseX and Y the mouth can be move all over the page.

Here is a link to my sketch 
http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/594186

```
// face myFace;
// circle myCircles;

void setup() {
    background( 126, 192, 238 );
    // setting up the size of the canvas 
    //800 is the width and 400 is the height
    size( 800, 400 );
    // Draws all geometry with smooth (anti-aliased) edges instead of rough edges
    smooth();

    //Creating a face and circle object
    // myFace = new face();
    // myCircles = new circle();
}
void draw() {


  println(mouseX + " : " + pmouseX);
    println(mouseY + " : " + pmouseY);
  //translate(mouseX - 800/2,mouseY);
        background( 126, 192, 238 );
        // The four parameters are RGBA to fill the ellipse with color
        fill( 234, 192, 134 );
        //Here I've added no stroke around the ellipse
        noStroke();
        //H                E             A             D 
        //I've now used the ellipse arugment because, i've ented my own values.
        //First value is x axis, second is the y axis, the 3rd (width) and 4th(height) values 
        //are the size of the ellipse
        ellipse( 400, 200, 215, 305 );
        // E           Y               E              S
        //L EYE
        fill( 0, 0, 0 );
        //Here I've added no stroke around the ellipse
        noStroke();
        ellipse( 350, 180, 30, 20 );
        //R EYE
        fill( 0, 0, 0 );
        //Here I've added no stroke around the ellipse
        noStroke();
        ellipse( 450, 180, 30, 20 );
        //P               U                P              I            L             S
        //EYE BALL
        fill( 255, 255, 255 );
        noStroke();
        ellipse( 350, 178, 12, 12 );
        //EYE BALL
        fill( 255, 255, 255 );
        noStroke();
        ellipse( 450, 178, 12, 12 );
        noFill();
        stroke( 0 );

        bezier( 450, 305, mouseX, mouseY, mouseX, mouseY, 350, 305 );


        if (mouseY <= 200) {
    mouseY=300;
    // Upper-left
  } 
          if (mouseX <= 400) {
    mouseX=400;
    // Upper-left
  }   
}
```

Comment: Pleas apply your code to the question. It is currently to broad to give a answer

Comment: Please specify your problem.

Comment: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/594186 i'm trying to add parameters to the bezier so it looks like the face is smiling, frowning, etc. but not all over the page.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks loads mate, it's way better than it was, so adding the max and min adds parameters to the mouse Y?